# Mysql, jar folder is connected yet it says no source and shows the the below exception

Tags: java, mysql, exception

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.initIDs()'
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.enter code hereinitIDs(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsNativeDispatcher.(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributes.get(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.read

---

Attributes(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$JarLoader.(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.lo`enter code here`adClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at sqlleanring.Main.main(Main.java:12)

Answer (score 0):

[It's a JVM bug](https://github.com/eclipse-openj9/openj9/issues/10945). Update your Java installation. That's not the only bug that ends up showing like this, there are more, but just about all of them require an update.